# My logo image is not working (can`t display it), using play 2.3.7 framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, scala, playframework

Here is the code. Note that i am using scala.js. I dont know what is going on my logo can`t display at all

```
@(title: String, header: Html = Html(""), content: Html = Html(""))(javascripts: Html)(implicit request: RequestHeader)
@import play.api.Play
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Play with scala.js showcase - @title</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("/public/images", "favicon.png")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("/public", "lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("/public", "stylesheets/main.css")" />
    @header
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>            
          </button>  
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="@routes.Assets.at("/public/images", "logo.png")"></a>
        </div>
       </div>

    </div>
```

Really need help
Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: No error just have the navbar and that's it

Comment: i think it should be @routes.Assets.at("images", "logo.png"). without "/public"

Comment: i dont't think so, bcz i got this error: [MatchError: (images,logo.png) (of class scala.Tuple2)]

Comment: Did you already try to use an `img` element within your `a` element, like this `<a class="navbar-brand"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/logo.png")"/></a>`?